# oozie sqoop shell action - sqoop : Command not found

Tags: shell, action, sqoop, oozie

I Am trying triggering a sqoop command through shell action. 
But i am getting the error - Sqoop: Command not found.

i could read the contents of a file from HDFS through shell action. But when i try to trigger sqoop or hive commands it is saying sqoop of Hive command not found.
i copied all libraries to some location and in oozie properties(oozie.libpath) i have given the path.

```
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/share/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=false
oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true
```

Am i missing anything here? Can some one please help me on this.

Comment: The Oozie ShareLibs contain all the JARs necessary to make a *Java call* to Hive, Sqoop, etc -- but not the *shell command* wrapper. If you want to run a Sqoop job from Oozie, just run a Sqoop action. Not a Shell action.

Comment: Plus, `oozie.libpath`is not meant to confirm the root dir for all ShareLibs. It is meant to add an *extra* bunch of JARs located in that directory (just like it does implicitly with the `lib/` sub-directory just beside your `workflow.xml`).

Comment: Also, for a Shell action, `oozie.use.system.libpath` refers to the JARs applicable to a Shell -- i.e. none. It makes sense only for Pig, Sqoop, Spark, etc.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter wouldn't running a Sqoop job from a shell action be useful if you need to run a number of fairly similar Sqoop jobs which can easily be parametrized in a shell script? If one thing would change I wouldn' t have to change all Sqoop actions, but just one shell script.

Comment: @VincentLous > if you can build a shell script to loop over multiple Sqoop executions, then, you can build a shell script to generate a Coordinator with multiple Sqoop actions and submit it intead of the previous one. After all, why do you use Oozie to begin with? Why not use a CRON somewhere with just shell scripts, and no error management?